# perl6/rakudo: Does perl6 enable "autoflush" by default?

Tags: stdout, raku, autoflush, rakudo-star

```
#!perl6
use v6;

my $message = "\nHello!\n\nSleep\nTest\n\n";

my @a = $message.split( '' );

for @a {
    sleep 0.3; 
    .print;
}
```

Does perl6 enable "autoflush" by default. With perl5 without enabling "outflush" I don't get this behavior.

Comment: It looks like the world has changed in the last six years.

Comment: Rakudo doesn't support autoflush. There's a note in [5to6-perlvar](https://docs.perl6.org/language/5to6-perlvar) under the `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH` entry.

Comment: What behavior? And note that unbuffered != autoflush ...  No one who has asked or answered any of the SO questions about autoflush, nor the Rakudo folks, seems to grasp this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rakudo enables autoflush by default; the specification is silent about the default.

Comment: Rakudo doesn't support autoflush. There's a note in [5to6-perlvar](https://docs.perl6.org/language/5to6-perlvar) under the `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH` entry.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the docs regarding auto flush:

‘No global alternative available. TTY handles are unbuffered by default, for others, set out-buffer to zero or use :!out-buffer with open on a specific IO::Handle.’

So any printing to stdout is unbuffered and I guess would behave similar to auto flushed stdout of perl5.

Other handles depend on the out-buffer size set.

Comment: unbuffered is not the same as autoflush. No one who has answered any of the SO questions about autoflush, nor the Rakudo folks, seems to grasp this.